# XamlParseException, Set connectionId threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When I run below Xaml I get error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Set connectionId threw an
>   exception.' Line number '18' and line position '14'.'
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidCastException: Unable to convert
>   'System.Windows.Style' object to 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeView'
>   type.

Please do not mark this question as duplicate because I checked all that similar questions in SO and could not find an answer that works.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="xxx">
        <Grid>
            <local:ButtonEx ToolTipService.ToolTipClosing="ButtonEx_ToolTipClosing"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeViewBookmarks" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonEx_ToolTipClosing(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

class ButtonEx : Button
{
}
```

If I remove: `ToolTipService.ToolTipClosing="ButtonEx_ToolTipClosing"`, or remove: `EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"`, or remove `x:Name="treeViewBookmarks"` - No error.

If I use `Button` instead of `ButtonEx` - No error.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question.

It looks like this is a bug in the WPF `PresentationBuildTasks` component.

As you know, building a WPF project causes a lot of compiler-generated code to be injected into your UI classes.

E.g. your `MainWindow` class will additionally get something like this:

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public void InitializeComponent()
{
    if (!_contentLoaded)
    {
        _contentLoaded = true;
        Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/WpfApp1;component/mainwindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
    }
}

[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
void IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
{
    if (connectionId == 2)
    {
        treeViewBookmarks = (TreeView)target;
    }
    else
    {
        _contentLoaded = true;
    }
}

[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
void IStyleConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
{
    if (connectionId == 1)
    {
        EventSetter eventSetter = new EventSetter();
        eventSetter.Event = Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent;
        eventSetter.Handler = new MouseButtonEventHandler(TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick);
        ((Style)target).Setters.Add(eventSetter);
    }
}
```

Those `Connect` methods are generated incorrectly.

If you replace the `ButtonEx` in the `DataTemplate` with a `Button`, those `Connect` methods will look like this:

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
void IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
{
    if (connectionId == 3)
    {
        treeViewBookmarks = (TreeView)target;
    }
    else
    {
        _contentLoaded = true;
    }
}

[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
void IStyleConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
{
    switch (connectionId)
    {
    case 1:
        ((Button)target).AddHandler(ToolTipService.ToolTipClosingEvent, new ToolTipEventHandler(ButtonEx_ToolTipClosing));
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        EventSetter eventSetter = new EventSetter();
        eventSetter.Event = Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent;
        eventSetter.Handler = new MouseButtonEventHandler(TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick);
        ((Style)target).Setters.Add(eventSetter);
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

See, the `connectionId` is different.

You should report this issue to Microsoft. Something is going wrong in the `PresentationBuildTasks` for your case.

Comment: Where can I report this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may be weird, but it worked for me. Following is what I did.

> Windows Settings -> Time & Language -> Date & Time -> Additional
> Settings -> Sync now.

After this I restarted Visual Studio and everything worked as expected.