# Placing a conditional in XAML throws System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException exception in the InitializeComponent method at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I am trying to apply conditionals in the XAML code directly depending on the build configuration.
For example, I would like a piece of XAML code only put in the view in case of a Trial build configuration.

I have followed the tutorials that I have found which are below:

- [Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940157/1624552)
- [Conditionals in XAML](https://patriksvensson.se/posts/2017/12/conditionals-in-xaml)
- [COMPILATION DIRECTIVES FOR CONTROLLING XAML CONTENT](https://kmyr.dev/post/compilation-directives-for-controlling-xaml-content)

so my code looks like below.

**AssemblyInfo.cs** :

```
#if TRIAL
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My App Trial Mode")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("This is a full free trial")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("trial-mode", "MySolution.ProjectNamespace")]
#endif
```

**MyView.xaml** :

```
<Window x:Class="MyProjectNamespace.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:trial="trial-mode"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc">

      <mc:AlternateContent>
         <mc:Choice Requires="trial">
            
            <Separator Margin="7,0,10,8"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSeparatorVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>

            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource MyStackPanelStyle}"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=IsAlertVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
                
                <Image Height="18"
                       Width="18"
                       Margin="0,2,0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Stretch="Uniform"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       Source="{StaticResource myIcon}"/>
                
                <TextBlock Margin="12,2,0,0"
                           FontStyle="Normal"
                           FontWeight="Thin"
                           FontSize="12"
                           Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"
                           Text="{x:Static p:Resources.MyAlertText}">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            
       </mc:Choice>
       <mc:Fallback>
                <!-- Content to show in case of no trial. In my case I leave it empty. -->
       </mc:Fallback>
    </mc:AlternateContent>


    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"
            Margin="1,1.5,1,2"
            Padding="2"/>

</Window>
```

In design time there are no compilation errors but when I execute it an exception is thrown in the InitializeComponent method within the constructor in the MyView.xaml.cs code behind:

```
public partial class MyView: UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is the following:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set connectionId threw an
> exception.'
>
> Inner Exception InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to type
> 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'

Below the screenshot:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, here is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043206/xamlparseexception-set-connectionid-threw-an-exception), did you try the method in it and it worked

Comment: @GetValue In my case, removing the outer stackpanel (the one provided in this post) which embeds the Image and the TextBlock is working. I have removed the stackpanel and put the Image and TextBlock without using the StackPanel and now it works.